# Increase a number but always keep first digit

Tags: javascript

```
Case 1:
input: 145
output: 146

Case 2:
input 199
output 1001

Case 3:
input: 59
output 501

Case 4:
input: 99
output: 901
```

So the first number should never change.

Reason is the first number is a classification (1-9). The number following is serial numbers.

So 199 is classifcation '1' and serial number 99. The next serial number is 1001. Henche the odd logic (I didn't decide this).

Any smart way of doing this?

Comment: How do you reconcile your case #4 and "*the first number should never change*"?

Comment: I don't get case 2. 199 + 1 => 200 => keep first digit => 100

Comment: @PM77-1, it's 9

Comment: Why are there two case 4?

Comment: @CamilleWintz First digit in case 2 is 1. The one I want to keep

Comment: But why does it go to 1001 and not 1100?

Comment: Cause 1001 is the first number in "1000"

Comment: Why doesn't case 5 keep the first digit 9?

Comment: @Barmar Bad case. I removed it.

Comment: Shouldn't it be 199 -> 1000 and 59 -> 500 and 99 -> 900?

Comment: @SimpleJ. Noop. The first digit represents something, the other numbers are serial numbers.

Comment: You need to explain the logic clearly. I think if you do that, you should find that you're able to program it as well, since programming is simply translating logic to a language.

Comment: @Barmar I updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert the number to a string. Get the first digit as the first character of the string, and the rest as the remaining characters. If the rest is all 9, increment it to that many 0's + 1, otherwise just add 1 to it. Then concatenate this back with the original first digitl

```js
function increment_serial(input) {
  var str = input.toString();
  var first = str[0];
  var rest = str.substr(1);
  if (rest.match(/^9+$/)) {
    var newrest = rest.replace(/9/g, '0') + '1';
  } else {
    newrest = parseInt(rest, 10) + 1;
  }
  return first + newrest;
}

console.log(increment_serial(145));
console.log(increment_serial(199));
console.log(increment_serial(59));
console.log(increment_serial(99));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have two variables, a prefix and the number:

```
var prefix = "5";
var number = 99;
var output = prefix + number;
alert(output);
number = number + 1;
output = prefix + number;
alert(output);
```

And here is the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xedret/0ujgjsbj/

Comment: Please use Stack Snippet instead of jsfiddle for the demo.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function incrementNumberLeavingFirst(number) {
    var numberAsString = number+"";
    incrementedNumber = parseInt(numberAsString.slice(1))+1
    return parseInt(numberAsString[0]+incrementedNumber);
}

alert(incrementNumberLeavingFirst(599))
```

We take an integer, `number`, as the first parameter of our function. This is the number that we want to increment.

Adding a string to an integer in JavaScript converts the integer to a string, so we get the string version of the `number` parameter by adding an empty string to it, and store that in the variable `numberAsString`.

Then, we take all of that string except for the first character using `numberAsString.slice(1)`, convert it to an integer using `parseInt`, and add one. This increments the number (excluding the first digit). We store the incremented number in a variable called `incrementedNumber`.

Finally, we concatenate the first digit of the number to the incremented number (note that the first digit is still a string, so this converts `incrementedNumber` to a string, and adds the first number to the start of that string. Then we convert the whole thing to an integer using `parseInt`, and return it.